# How to return an aggregate on many elasticsearch documents with Spring Boot Data Elasicsearch?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-jpa

I have a problem with my Spring-Boot 3.1.1 application + spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch version 3.1.1.

The index of my cluster is configured as follows:

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "id": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "brand": {
                "type": "keyword"
            },
            "tradename": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "date": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "strict_date_optional_time"
            },
            "color": {
                "type": "text"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My service:

```
@Service
public class VehicleService {

    @Autowired
    private VehicleRepository vehicleRepository;

    public List<BrandDTO> getBrands() {
        List<Vehicle> vehicleList = vehicleRepository.findDistinctBrandsOrdered();
        System.out.println(vehicleList);

        List<BrandDTO> brandDTOList = vehicleList.stream()
                .map(Vehicle::getBrand)
                .distinct()
                .sorted()
                .map(brand -> {
                    BrandDTO brandDTO = new BrandDTO();
                    brandDTO.setBrand(brand);
                    return brandDTO;
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return brandDTOList;
    }
}
```

And my repository:

```
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Query;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.ElasticsearchRepository;
...

@Repository
public interface VehicleRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Vehicle, Long> {

    Vehicle findByCountryAndPlate(String country, String plate);

    @Query("{\"match_all\": {}},\"size\": 0,\"aggs\": " +
            "{\"distinct_brand\": {\"terms\": {\"field\": " +
            "\"brand\",\"size\": 10000,\"order\": {\"_key\": " +
            "\"asc\"}}}}")
    List<Vehicle> findDistinctBrandsOrdered();

}
```

If my index has 50 documents, the results are returned perfectly. But if my index has several hundred documents, I get the following message:

Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
[Request processing failed: org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.UncategorizedElasticsearchException: [es/search] failed: [search_phase_execution_exception] all shards failed] with root cause
co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch._types.ElasticsearchException: [es/search] failed: [search_phase_execution_exception] all shards failed

If I test my query on the same index with several hundred documents by sending:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "distinct_brand": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "brand",
        "size": 10000,
        "order": {
          "_key": "asc"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I still get the results.

Why doesn't this work with Spring Boot and the same query?

And more importantly, why does it work on Spring Boot just by reducing the number of documents in my index?

I corrected the yellow to green status by modifying the index with:
PUT /_all/_settings

```
{
   "index": {
     "number_of_replicas": 0
   }
}
```

But that didn't change anything.